# Apache RewriteRule won't work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite http://rewrite.local/de to http://rewrite.local/test.htm using Apache?

I've made sure RewriteEngine is on and working. I've tried all of these rules but none of them are working:

```
RewriteRule http://rewrite.local/de http://rewrite.local/test.htm

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rewrite.local\/de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rewrite.local/test.htm

RewriteRule ^(.*)/de$ http://rewrite.local/test.htm
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `.htaccess` will redirect both http://rewrite.local/de and http://rewrite.local/de/ to http://rewrite.local/test.html :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^de/?$ test.html [L,R=301]
```

You musn't take account of the domain in `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: "You musn't take account of the domain in .htaccess rules."
But what if you want to restrict a rule to only a certain domain? Isn't RewriteCond the way to go than?

Comment: Yes it is. This domain restriction is one of the `RewriteCond` roles, you'll never take account of the domain in a **rule**, the rule regex will only be applied on the request uri.